# gsutil login using installed application json file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gsutil

I want to use gsutil to list files in a google cloud bucket.
I installed the google cloud sdk, my problem is that i have a credential file client_secrets.json that is for a installed application, it looks something like this

```
{
  "installed": {
    "client_id": "837647042410-75ifg...usercontent.com",
    "client_secret":"asdlkfjaskd",
    "redirect_uris": ["http://localhost", "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"],
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
  }
}
```

I know you can authenticate using
`gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=credentials.json`
but that only works for service accounts and mine is an installed application credential and it didn't work.

Instead of using gcloud auth I've tried to switch to do authentication using boto by running
`gcloud config set pass_credentials_to_gsutil false`
and updating the .boto config file to update the client_id and client_secret manually from my file but when i run `gsutil config` to run the new credentials it keeps asking me to login through the browser to provide a code after a manual login:

```
Please navigate your browser to the following URL:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=20487....
Enter the authorization code:
```

but this is an app that should not need a user to login since i already have a credential file.

What am i missing? how can i authenticate using an install app client_secrets.json using gsutil.

Answer (score 1):

This [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/end-user-installed) provides a complete workflow to use an installed application credentials, you need to configure your application and save your credentials in a client_secrets.json file and after the whole configuration and authentication process you will be able to use the gcloud/ gsutil command. You can refer to this Public Google [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20service%20account,%2Fsa%2Dprivate%2Dkey.) for managing your secret key to create and authenticate your service account key.

You can also refer to the [stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43531595/can-you-pass-a-keyfile-json-to-gsutil) where a googler has explained how to pass key.json file to gsutil by using .boto configuration for your json file.

Comment: @Klam posted an answer , Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a credential. Your file is a OAuth2 Client Id (of type Desktop). The tools use it to initiate a OAuth 2 authentication, and yes you need to log in because there isn't any credential in this file.

The clientID and client secret are used to authenticate your log in request with your login and your password, it's not a credential of you, just for the OAuth2 protocol!

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific not to lead to confusion, when i talk about having credential file it's referring to OAuth credentials not the credentials to the endpoint, but so does the service account credential file and gsutils is able to use that file for authentication as i described on my original post. So how can i use an installed application credential file with gsutil or gcloud? and if it's not supported then what is my alternative without having to write an app to do so?

Comment: sorry i actually mean without user intervention :) and yes, installed application is the only credential i have available to me.

Comment: Installed OAuth clientID application can't be used by gsutil or gcloud. You need to perform your authentication flow, for a user, with that file before and then to save the credential in a file (I can share the format in you want) and then gsutil and gcloud will be able to use it.

Comment: In your current file, you haven't secret (Ok, you have a client secret, but as I explained it is a secret to initiate a OAuth2 authentication flow, not a secret that represent your identity. Use a service account key file instead.